# Rows cannot be programmatically added to datagrid

Tags: c#

How do I resolve this error:

> Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound.

From the below code:

```
  string str = "Er.fName,Er.lName";
      DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
      DataSet info = this.GetData.getInfo("SELECT 0 AS ErNo, Er.EmpID, (Er.fName&''&sr.lName) AS [Employee Name], Ed.DeptNo AS [Dept No] FROM (EmployeeReg AS Er INNER JOIN EmployeeDept AS Ed ON Er.EmpId = Er.EmpId)  WHERE Ed.DeptId=" + (object) DeptID + " AND  Ed.Status=0  AND Er.EmpStatus=1 ORDER BY " + str, "EmployeeDept");
if (info.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0) {
    for (int index = 0; index < info.Tables[0].Rows.Count; ++index)
    //error from the code blw 
    this.dgvPrint.Rows.Add((object) 0, (object)(index + 1), (object) info.Tables[0].Rows[index]["Emp Name"].ToString(), (object) info.Tables[0].Rows[index]["Emp No"].ToString(), (object) info.Tables[0].Rows[index]["EmpId"].ToString());
}
if (this.dgvPrint.Rows.Count > 0) 
    this.btnPrint.Enabled = true;
else 
    this.btnPrint.Enabled = false;
```

Comment: Please format your code to readable format.

Comment: Its very clear error. When you have bound datagrid you cant add items to it.

Comment: What is the data-source of the Datagridview ????

Comment: The correct thing to do is add the data to the datacollection (database, memory, List<thing> and then refresh the grid...

Comment: Manipulate the source, not the view, then update the view to get around this error. If you specifically wish to target the datarows, you can make use of the row's clone property.

Answer (score 0):

```
var table = info.Tables[0];
table.Rows.Add(new object[] {
      0, 
      index + 1,
      table.Rows[index]["Emp Name"], 
      table.Rows[index]["Emp No"],
      table.Rows[index]["EmpId"]
});
```

or:

```
var table = info.Tables[0];
var new = table.NewRow();
new["colllName"] = 1;
new["colllName 2"] = 2;
//ect...
table.Rows.Add(new);
```